# Reading 1 line at a time from multiple files

Tags: python, file, io

I have a bunch of filenames. I need to read one line at a time from each of these files, do some processing and then read the one line again from each of these files, do some processing and so on.

I'm looking for suggestions on how to do this in a more Pythonic way. I know the number of lines present in each file so I'm hard-coding it for now, but I'd like to not have to do that.

UPDATE:
The files all have the same number of lines.

UPDATE2:
There are at least 30 different files.

```
filenames = []
line_count = 400
fileobjs = [open(i, 'r') for i in filenames]
for i in xrange(line_count):
    lines = []
    for each_fo in fileobjs:
        for each_line in each_fo:
            lines.append(each_line)
            break
    process(lines)
```

Comment: Each file has the same number of lines?

Comment: Yes, they all have the same number of lines. I will update the question. Thank you.

Comment: I think it might be cleaner to read everything using `file_obj.readlines`. I'd also suggest using `with` block to open files as that handles closing as well and it's considered pythonic. Do you have any reason to read lines one by one?

Comment: Yes, its what I require. The number of lines may be very very large so I dont wish to read it all into memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
lines = [next(fo) for fo in fileobjs]
process(lines)
```

Answer (score 2):

What about this?

```
from itertools import izip_longest
for file_lines in izip_longest(*map(open,filenames)):
    for line in file_lines:
        if line:
            # process line
```

Answer (score 1):

This will read both the files line by line at a time

```
 with open('File1','r') as FileA, open('File2','r') as FileB:
     for lineA,lineB in zip(FileA,FileB):
          print lineA,lineB
```

Comment: `zip` sounds like a good idea to me, but what if we have more than two files? What if we have a `fileobjs` list and we don't know how big it is?

Answer (score 1):

```
filenames = []
files = [open(f, mode='r') for f in filenames]
for line in files[0]:
    lines = [file.readline() for file in files]
    process(lines)
```